# Change video dimensions iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, video-editing

On my macOS laptop I change video dimensions easily using ffmpeg, normally something like

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -vf “scale=iw/2:ih/2” our.mp4
```

On the iPhone I can’t find out how I can resize a video that I recorded.

How do I do that (for free)?

I want to make saved videos smaller (they have already been recorded, I know I can change the recording dimensions in settings)

Comment: did you try Video Compressor for iOS on the App Store, it's free and works on iPhone and iPad.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I can’t find it.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-compressor/id482465886?mt=8

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don’t want to pay for this

Comment: ok try this one https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-compress-reduce-movie-size-shrink-video/id1163846234?mt=8